# How to remove "" Object / array using jquery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have the following result of an ajax request

```html
["[1449270000000, 21]", "[1449356400000, 41]", "[1449442800000, 60]",...
```

I would like to know how to remove "" using jQuery. I've tried several things and I could not.

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: I'd fix the source of error. Why do you have such structure?

Comment: Here is an option: `theArray.map(el => JSON.parse(el))`

Comment: I think you want to evaluate the string, using eval is not advised though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can try is make a loop on the different element of your ajax reply with `.each` and for each of them test a `JSON.parse(yourstring)` it will give you an array for each string.

Comment: This solved $.each(data.ctl, function(i, value) { data_ctl.push(JSON.parse(value)); }); - thanks